# Type mismatch error on ‘toDecimal(body.results[1].position.lon)’ - Azure maps

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-maps

Hello i am using the azure maps Geocoding API to extract lat lon information from address from flat files loaded into a datalake - i have been getting a type mismatch error when i try to use the function ‘toDecimal(body.results[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbn2a.png).position.lon)’ in the derived column ( data flow task in ADF)
[image]

The error says "No field named results in the hierarchial structure. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you don't import the schema of the body in the external call transformation, you will get this kind of errors.

**Before importing schema:**

[image]

To resolve it, delete the next transformations after the **externalCall** and first import the schema of the body in the **externalCall** transformation.

[image]

The schema will be generated dynamically in the `Type` of the body. Now, create the columns in the derived column and you can see the error got resolved and it will give the desired result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get the coordinates of the second result, not the first (arrays are zero index). In that case, it's possible that there isn't a second result (especially if you are doing street addresses), and thus `toDecimal` is getting null or undefined as an input.